# How to copy files from sharepoint into blob storage azure data factory v2 using Odata linked service

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

Can any one help in understanding procedure of copying excel  file from  share point  to azure Blob storage through  Azure Data Factory pipelines. I am struggling while creating Odata linked service. What is service url in odata linked service? 
I am using rest apis provided in link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest) as a service url :https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/

authentication type: basic

when I test connection I outputs a weird error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFYuS.png)

I have tried the following articles so far.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odata

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest

Note: when I try these rest api urls from browser they work fine I can download files and so on.
is there any other way of achieving this goal??

Comment: Instead of adding too many external links you should show some code and or error.

Comment: @Atul Dwivedi we are using azure portal for creating pipelines so there is no code.

Comment: @Atul Dwivedi I have also added the screen shot of an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint online is supported by OData linked service through AAD SPN with Cert authentication type.

A cert using by OData connector can be created and configured by following the below article, which will guide you to connect the cert to an AAD app for invoking SPO Online with an app only access token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread