# Azure Data Factory and SharePoint

Tags: azure, sharepoint, onedrive, azure-data-factory

I have some Excel files stored in SharePoint online. I want copy files stored in SharePoint folders to Azure Blob storage.

To achieve this, I am creating a new pipeline in Azure Data factory using Azure Portal. What are possible ways to copy files from SharePoint to Azure blob store using Azure Data Factory pipelines?

I have looked at all linked services types in Azure data factory pipeline but couldn't find any suitable type to connect to SharePoint.

Comment: Shared an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54917401/2398895

Comment: is there any specific reason behind using Azure Data Factory? I think Power Automate (Flow) could also be used to achieve the same

Comment: I had the same [requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902968/azure-data-factory-401-error-when-calling-get-request-on-sharepoint-online-api)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than directly accessing the file in SharePoint from Data Factory, you might have to use an intermediate technology and have Data Factory call that. You have a few of options:

1. [Use a Logic App to move the file](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5893/transfer-files-from-sharepoint-to-blob-storage-with-azure-logic-apps/)
2. [Use an Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/sharepoint-webhooks-using-azure-functions)
3. Use a custom activity and write your own C# to copy the file.

To call a Logic App from ADF, you [use a web activity](http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/06/execute-logic-apps-in-azure-data.html). 
You can [directly call an Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) now.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a linked service of type '[File system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system)' by providing the directory URL as 'Host' value. To authenticate the user, provide username and password/AKV details. 
Note: Use [Self-hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime)

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I've tested multiple combinations for the URL, but none are working. Maybe only applicable to a local sharepoint and not Online?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic app to fetch data from Sharepoint and load it to azure blob storage and now you can use azure data factory to fetch data from blob even we can set an event trigger so that if any file comes into blob container the azure pipeline will automatically trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Automate (https://make.powerautomate.com/) to do this task automatically:

1. Create an Automated cloud flow trigger whenever a new file is dropped in a SharePoint

[image: Automated cloud flow]

2. Use any mentioned trigger as per your requirement and fill in the SharePoint details

[image: SharePoint Trigger]

3. Add an action to create a blob and fill in the details as per your use case

[image: Create Blob action]

***By using this you will be pasting all the SharePoint details to the BLOB without even using ADF.***

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was true at the time, but in the last few years, Microsoft has published guidance on [how to copy documents from a SharePoint library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online). You can copy file from SharePoint Online by using Web activity to authenticate and grab access token from SPO, then passing to subsequent Copy activity to copy data with HTTP connector as source.

I ran into some issues with  large files and Logic Apps. It turned out there were some extremely large files to be copied from that SharePoint library. SharePoint has a default limit of 100 MB buffer size, and the Get File Content action doesn’t natively support chunking.

I successfully pulled the files with the web activity and copy activity. But I found the SharePoint permissions configuration to be a bit tricky. I blogged my  process [here](https://datasavvy.me/2021/12/07/copying-large-files-from-sharepoint-online/).
You can use a binary dataset if you just want to copy the full file rather than read the data.

If my file is located at `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/libraryname/folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile.CSV`, the URL I need to retrieve the file is `https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/libraryname/folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile.CSV')/$value`.

Be careful about when you get your auth token. Your auth token is valid for 1 hour. If you copy a bunch of files sequentially, and it takes longer than that, you might get a timeout error.