# Copy data transfer from sharepoint to datalake

Tags: azure, sharepoint, automation, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

EDIT:

I have gone though "copy data from sharepoint to blob storage" under this thread.
[Azure Data Factory and SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868998/azure-data-factory-and-sharepoint)

But I am looking for a solution to copy data from sharepoint to datalake Gen2. Any pointers or examples would be useful. Thanks.

My raw data(csv format)is on a sharepoint folder. I am trying to automate data transfer when ever the raw data changes. Like I can update a csv file on sharepoint.  That event should trigger data transfer from sharepoint to datalake.
I have seen few articles about using logic apps and datafactory to do data transfer.
But my scenario is to trigger that pipeline whenever the raw data gets updated on Sharepoint.
Can someone please throw some light? Thanks.
Regards